# Text Analytics ong Big Data

Tags: bigdata

Could you guys recommend some good tools or frameworks that can perform text analytics on the Big data(multi structured) and should be open source?

Comment: do you mean search engine?

Comment: what kind of analytics you want to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Look at NLTK http://nltk.org/ and Google Prediction API. I think It's good stuff.